# Meteor app http GET only working on one device

Tags: ios, http, meteor, get

We are uploading our app onto test flight, and the app's http GET calls are only working for one user. It is the user who originally uploaded the app.

Is that because we need to register more devices somehow? or whitelist people?

Test flight doesn't require you to register devices any more. But we can't figure it out.

UPDATE:

It turns out that it is the server side methods that aren't working at all, except for that one person. It is not a problem with the http package. Why are the server methods not working?

Comment: What do you mean by http get calls? Does the app install on several devices?

Comment: Yes the app successfully installs on multiple devices. I am using the HTTP package of meteor to make my REST calls.